# Need help straightening edges for photoshop drawing

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, mask

I got this design here and after I made the selection, the edges were all jagged, I tried masking it with contrast and adjusting curves but this is the best I could get it.

Anyone know how I could straighten up all the edges so I can save it as a file and resize them without the edges becoming jagged.

https://filebin.net/cc1wjjmcmf5w027f

[image]

Comment: Why isnt this a vector file?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Any time you find yourself trying to do work like this in Photoshop, you can be almost certain you are using the wrong kind of application.  Instead, use a vector image editor to redraw it. It's not a complex design, and should only take a few minutes to recreate in vector image editing software, such as Illustrator, Inkscape (free), CorelDraw, Affinity Designer, etc.

Answer (score 11):

The way to have this re-sizeable without pixelation (jagged edges) is to

Re-draw this in a vector application and

save it as a .pdf (or any vector format)

Photoshop is a raster (pixel based) application and will show pixelation when resized.